# Vagrant up - execute sh file fails

Tags: vagrant, sh, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I have a simple vagrant file which calls sh file in the provision phase:
[image]

Inside script.sh I have wget command that fails with error 403 (Forbidden).

Same error I get when running the script manually from the VM. But If I create new sh file with the SAME CONTENT, then wget will pass successfully!

*I know there is several ways in vagrant to do provisions, but please stick on this specific use case.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of this strange behaviour.
Since I have created the sh file in MAC env it was not compatible with unix line endings format. running "dos2unix script.sh".

For detialed information visit:
http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/